# Foundation zurb nav not showing in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation

It's the first time I use foundation for my Rails project. In the past I only used Bootstrap.

I followed the steps described here http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/gem-install.php#simple2 and I can't manage to create a simple nav ( http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php ).

It applies some style, but not fully (for example, it's not black).

I followed the automatic and the manual install as well. The funny thing is that some styles work. For example, applying style "button" to a link works.

I tried many things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the link you supplied is outdated (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/gem-install.php#simple2)

Here are the updated instructions:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/rails.php